# flickring 1.5” or 2” column in screen of 17" macbook pro early 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, flickr

I am using it by mid 2012.

I was sitting out door for 2hrs at evening and keep working with mac book; and at middle of the screen around 1.5" or 2" starts flickering. Sometime it stops flickering and back to normal. I did clear PRAM and NVRAM by pressing option+command+R+P.

What is the problem? and what is solution for it?

Is that OSX problem or hardware problem or bad graphics?

Comment: Same question same user but different user names: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272677/flickering-1-5-or-2-column-in-screen-of-mac-book-pro-early-2011

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a replacement program for your model:
http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Here are the affected models:

- MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2011)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2012)
- MacBook Pro (17-inch Early 2011)
- MacBook Pro (17-inch Late 2011)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15 inch, Early 2013)

I wish 13-inch mid-2012 was included as well, because I have a similar issue.